# Gotham Medium / black font definition in css

Tags: css, fonts

I was trying to define gotham font in css however it doesnt seem to work, do i need to download it and include a link to it or do something else for it to work?

my code:

```
.display-4{
    font-family: Gotham-Black;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to download it and add the path to the font's location.
More info can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp